# Split for ng repeat item?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Simple question- if I have this in my controller:

```
$scope.somedata = 'Item 1, Item 2'; // set from something else
```

is there a way to split somedata for my view in a ngRepeat expression?  Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata | split(',')">{{item}}</div>
```

which doesnt work...

Or do I have to do

```
$scope.somedata = 'Item 1, Item 2'; // set from something else
$scope.items = somedata.split(',');
```

and then

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items>{{item}}</div>
```

I think I'm not really understanding what I can do in an expression in AngularJS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The string the right of the `|` is resolved to the name of a filter (usually they are string formatting filters, but the angular team has also provided the `filter` filter, which returns a filtered array (a bit misleading because the two share the same name).  You could create your own split filter to accomplish what you want:

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('split', function() {
    return function(input, delimiter) {
      var delimiter = delimiter || ',';

      return input.split(delimiter);
    } 
  });
```

You could use the filter like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata | split">
```

Or specify a delimiter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata | split:,">
```

Consider the above pseudo-code because I haven't tested it.

Le plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hk6F0Y6p5YAXv6fyXfSz?p=preview

Answer (score 31):

I guess I'm too late, 
but why not simply do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata.split(',')">{{item}}</div>
```

works just fine.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pevotaxi/1/edit?html,js,output) for evidence!

Comment: this answer solves the problem more easily; and I thought defining a filter would be easier but in the end this is a nicer solution. Don't know if its the "Angular" way of doing things but heck I like it.

Comment: Simplest solution! this should be the correct  answer

Answer (score 0):

commented delimiter here

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('split', function() {
    return function(input, delimiter) {
      //var delimiter = delimiter || ',';

      return input.split(delimiter);
    } 
  });
```

You could use the filter like so:
also added track by $index to avoid crash due to duplicate values

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata | split:',' track by $index">
```