# ionic , angular , split result and display in line item

Tags: angularjs, function, split, ionic-framework, records

I am learning ionic with angular. I can get the result from my dataservice. However, I want to split the result and display separately.

For example, data.record  returns "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" string. Now, I wanted to split it so that it can display a, b, c and so on in a different line item. How do I do that ?

```
   <ion-view view-title="DataItem">
        <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content ng-controller="DataCtrl">
        {{data.record}}
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: I know that you have found a solution that allows you to split this string, but you might consider looking at designing your data service to return JSON rather than comma separated values;  JSON is much more standard for APIs, and is much more flexible to work with.

Comment: My data looks like this and i need to display all the colors in different line.  
  
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "color":"white,yellow"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "color":"white,blue"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "color":"red,green"}
]}

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the reply. I did more search on the ng-repeat. The below help to resolve the answer based on your recommendation.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somedata.split(',')">{{item}}</div>
```

Another post on splitting the data is also found here.

[Split for ng repeat item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718609/split-for-ng-repeat-item)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-repeat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output..

```
Looping with ng-repeat:

Jani
Hege
Kai
```

Example provided from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_array

If you are looking to split the values use the following example

```
$scope.mySplit = function(string, nb) {
    $scope.array = string.split(',');
    return $scope.result = $scope.array[nb];
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. This will work if my data is in an array format. But my data is in string now. "a,b,c,d,e,f". How do I split that and pass it over to ng_repeat as an array ?

Comment: Thank you. Seus. Got it.